# How to determine AWS EC2 network performance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, bandwidth

I am using an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance that was set up and configured by someone else (i.e. I do not have access to the management console). This instance is primarily used to download files and sync to an S3 bucket, which I have automated with shell scripts. However, I do not know the instance type or the network performance, so I cannot optimize the downloads. For example, I need to know how many simultaneous downloads the instance can perform. How can I determine the AWS EC2 instance type and the network performance (i.e. download/upload speed)?

Comment: How would knowing the instance type help work out what to do? Just curl or ftp some things in. I did a test a while back, I can't remember the results but between instances I got better than 50MB/sec. Bigger instances will get much more.

Comment: @Tim AWS's documentation indicates approximate network speeds per instance type. It'll give at least a rough indication of capability.

Comment: Really? I've only seen low/medium/high, though EBS network speed can be specified. This would be more useful https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/

Answer (score 4):

Doing `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type` from the instance will give you the instance type from the EC2 Instance Metadata Service.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use iperf (https://github.com/esnet/iperf), but it's best to have a second server (from the target network if possible) in order to have realistic results.

If you have the right repos you can install using apt (apt-get install iperf)

There are lots of tests which you can run using that tool.

Answer (score 0):

Log into the AWS Management Console, go to EC2, find your instance and look at the Instance Type column.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to the management console. Post updated to include this information.

Comment: you can still retrieve the instance type when ssh-ing the machine, using the instance metadata: instance_type=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon documentation tells you how to [benchmark AWS the network performance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/).

Enable repo

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install iperf iperf3
```

Install iperf

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install git gcc make
git clone https://github.com/esnet/iperf
cd iperf
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
 # optionally run "make clean" to free up disk space
 # by removing artifacts in the build tree.
sudo make clean
sudo ldconfig
```

Configure listener

```
sudo iperf3 -s -p 80
```

Run the test

```
sudo iperf3 -c 10.0.2.176 -i 1 -t 60 -V -p 80
```